# TaskCompletionSource asynchronous return

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have the following class:

```
public class Npc
{
    private string _text = "";

    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs;

    public void AddText(string text)
    {
        this._text += text;
    }

    public void SendOk()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this._text, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

        this._text = "";
    }

    public bool SendYesNo()
    {
        tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        MessageBox.Show(this._text, "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

        this._text = "";

        return tcs.Task.Result;
    }

    public void SetResult(bool result)
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult(result);
    }
}
```

I want the method `SendYesNo` to return the `tcs.Result` value only after it's been set using the `SetResult` method (the `SetResult` method will be called from another part of the code).

However, when I execute `SendYesNo` my program just hangs (it waits for the result). Is there a way to make `SendYesNo` ashcyronous so I can set the result?

**NOTE:** I know that making the method async and calling the await keyword will make it async. However, I cannot call the await keyword simply because these methods are used in a JavaScript script.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: I'm sure there's a very bad design/architecture decisions behind not being able to use asynchronous code...

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible if you make `SendYesNo` return without waiting for the result to arrive. It *must* return `Task<bool>`. If you cannot make this work because of some JavaScript issues than you have lost.

Maybe you can make `SendYesNo` take a callback (an `Action`) that you call when the task is completed.

Comment: How would I go on applying the suggested solution with Actions?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more code. The general idea would be to use callback style which is very customary with JavaScript.